# Generating rows by splitting a value into three character chunks

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

Example data:

```
'255002001255255001255001004002255007002'
```

There is a formula that every 3 characters belongs to a group, and within those 3 characters, the number belongs to a id. For example, the first 3 characters '255' belong to group 1 and 255 is related to an id in another table.

```
255
002
001
255
255
001
255
001
004
002
255
007
002
```

I need to store every 3 characters in the value above that comes from a table. I want to use a CTE that stores this information so I can reference it in a query to generate a report. Its a third party database so I only have read access.

I thought of using `SUBSTRING(tablevalue, 1,3)`, but dont know how to keep doing it for the entire value

Comment: What's your dbms? Could you provide your expect result?

Comment: Is using a temporary table an option?

Comment: I don't think using a CTE is appropriate (as it would be constantly recomputed, I still don't think most DBMss are smart enough to cache them between queries). Wouldn't a table-variable or temporary-table be more appropriate?

Comment: I would need something that is ssrs friendly because that is where the report will be generated from

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE.  For instance:

```
with cte as (
      select left(@str, 3) as group_id, substring(@str, 4, len(@str)) as rest
      union all
      select left(rest, 3) as group_id, substring(rest, 4, len(rest)) as rest
      from cte
      where len(rest) >= 3
     ),
     groups as (
      select group_id
      from cte
    ),
    . . .
```

Databases vary a bit in their string functions, so the exact function depend on the DB.  And, some databases require the `recursive` keyword.

Comment: This worked!! This is for sql server so just had to adjust some syntax in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server using recursive CTE:

```
WITH Strings(ID, String) AS (
  SELECT 1, '255002001255255001255001004002255007002' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '3334445556667778889990001112223334445556' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '44455566677788899900011122233344455566677'
), Numbers AS ( 
  SELECT 1 AS Number 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT Number + 1 
  FROM Numbers 
  WHERE Number + 1 <= 100
) 
SELECT String, Number, SUBSTRING(String, (Number - 1) * 3 + 1, 3) AS Result
FROM Strings
INNER JOIN Numbers ON Number <= CEILING(LEN(String) / 3.0)
ORDER BY String, Number
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0a653/23)

Recursive CTE is not actually required. Just about any technique to generate sequential numbers will work e.g. a table of numbers table or row_number on any table with few rows.

Answer (score 1):

If it were Oracle, something like this might do the job:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '255002001255255001255001004002255007002' from dual)
  3  select substr(col, 3 * (level - 1) + 1, 3) subs
  4  from test
  5  connect by level <= length(col) / 3;

SUBS
------------
255
002
001
255
255
001
255
001
004
002
255
007
002

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```